# Web scrape attributes that are not always included in the tag Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a URL 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm' using Beautiful Soup. 
I want to scrape the players name, their injury and the week of their injury

The players name is straight forward to scrape as it is text in a certain tag `<th>` and is always included in the tag. The week is an attribute `["data-stat"]` of the tag `<td>` and is also always included in the tag. The injury is also an attribute `["data-tip"]` of the same tag week is `<td>`, but it is only included in the tag when the player has an injury.

I tried using an if else statement for the injury status, so if the `<td>` tag contained an injury it would print the injury `["data-tip"]` and if not it would simply print "NA". From the code I wrote, it prints the first two players' names, injury and the week of the injury but the third player does not contain the injury attribute `["data-tip"]` in the `<td>` tag and the code would break and just print the first two players:

```
[['Danny Amendola'], 'Questionable: hamstring', 'week_1']
[['Armond Armstead'], 'Out: infection', 'week_1']
```

Outcome of my code! Experiencing a KeyError.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find("tbody")

player = containers.find_all("tr")
for tr in player:
    th = tr.find_all("th")
    name = [i.text for i in th]

    week = tr.td["data-stat"]

    injury = tr.td["data-tip"]
    if injury is None:
        injury = "NA"
        print([name, injury, week])
    else:
        print([name, injury, week])
```

The outcome I am looking for is for the code to print the player names, injury (if no injury print "NA") and the week of injury for all the players in the table. For example, the third player in the table does not have an injury for week 1, therefore his injury should print "NA":

```
[['Danny Amendola'], 'Questionable: hamstring', 'week_1']
[['Armond Armstead'], 'Out: infection', 'week_1']
[['Kyle Arrington'], 'NA', 'week_1']
```

The list should continue on for the rest of the players like this.

Comment: When loop coming to third `tr` can't see a `td` with `data-tip` and you try to equal it with `injury` before checking is None or not

Comment: @Kevin, when I run the code I am experiencing a `KeyError`. Is this the same error you are experiencing? And if so, can you add this to your question (where you are only printing two lists). This is helpful for others who might look at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm piggy backing on Jack Moody's solution (just adding the additional weeks), but here's the additional data/columns:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find("tbody")
head = page_soup.find("thead")


player = containers.find_all("tr")

weeks = head.find_all('th')
week_list = [i['data-stat'] for i in weeks][1:]

for week in week_list:
    for tr in player:
        th = tr.find_all("th")
        name = [i.text for i in th]
        
        td = tr.find('td', {'data-stat':week})
        week = td["data-stat"]
    
        try:
            injury = td["data-tip"]
            print([name, injury, week])
        except KeyError:
            injury = "NA"
            print([name, injury, week])
```

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful but when I run this code it displays the week 1 injuries for all weeks instead of progressing through and displaying the week 2 injuries for week 2, week 3 injuries for week 3 and so on..

Comment: @Kevin, not sure what you mean. I just re-ran it and it displays the week 1 injuries, followed by week 2, followed by week 3, etc.

Comment: @Kevin, AH OK! I totally see what you mean. The week number updates, but still diplays the week 1 injury. I'll fix that as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @Kevin, I fixed it. Tiny error in there. had to change `injury = tr.td["data-tip"]` to just `injury = td["data-tip"]`  I didn't want the first element in the row each time, just wanted that specific element

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `try` and `except` statement. You are running into a `KeyError` because if a player doesn't have an injury, then there won't be a `data-tip` attribute. After the line of code `week = # ...rest of code`, do the following:

```
try:
    injury = tr.td["data-tip"]
    print([name, injury, week])
except KeyError:
    injury = "NA"
    print([name, injury, week])
```

This will try to get the injury name and if it doesn't exist then it will set it to "NA". With that said, your fixed code shoud look like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find("tbody")

player = containers.find_all("tr")
for tr in player:
    th = tr.find_all("th")
    name = [i.text for i in th]

    week = tr.td["data-stat"]

    try:
        injury = tr.td["data-tip"]
        print([name, injury, week])
    except KeyError:
        injury = "NA"
        print([name, injury, week])
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! So this code is returning the players injuries for week 1. Do you know if i can loop this code in some way that it will return all injuries for each week; week1, week 2, week 3...etc instead of just returning the week 1 injuries? Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin you will need to work on that some, but it should just be another loop that does the code you have for each week

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the table, and then use `zip` to transpose the rows for each week:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm').text, 'html.parser')
_header, *data = d.find('table', {'id':'team_injuries'}).find_all('tr')
_all_data = [(lambda x:[c.find('th').text, *[i.attrs.get('data-tip', 'N/A') for i in x]])(c.find_all('td')) for c in data]
new_data = [dict(zip([i.text.rstrip() for i in _header.find_all('th')], c)) for c in _all_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'Player': 'Danny Amendola', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Questionable: hamstring', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: groin', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Doubtful: groin', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: groin', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: groin', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: groin', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Out: concussion', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: concussion', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: groin', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Probable: groin', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Probable: groin', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Probable: groin', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Probable: groin', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Probable: groin', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: groin', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Probable: groin', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Armond Armstead', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Out: infection', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Out: infection', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Out: infection', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Out: infection', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Out: infection', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Out: infection', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Out: infection', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Out: infection', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Out: infection', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Out: infection', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Out: infection', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Out: infection', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Out: infection', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Out: infection', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Out: infection', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Out: infection', '01/11vs. IND': 'Out: infection', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Out: infection'}, {'Player': 'Kyle Arrington', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: groin', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: groin', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: groin', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Probable: groin', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Probable: groin', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: groin', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Questionable: groin', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Probable: groin', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: groin', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: groin', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: groin', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: groin', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: groin', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Brandon Bolden', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Questionable: knee', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: knee', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Questionable: knee', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: knee', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: knee', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: knee', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: knee', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: knee', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: knee', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Questionable: knee', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Josh Boyce', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Doubtful: hip', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: hip', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Tom Brady', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Probable: right shoulder', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Probable: right shoulder', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Probable: right shoulder', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Probable: right shoulder', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Probable: shoulder', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Probable: right shoulder', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: shoulder', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Probable: right shoulder', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Probable: right shoulder', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Marcus Cannon', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: shoulder', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: shoulder', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: shoulder', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: ankle', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Marquice Cole', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Probable: hamstring', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: hamstring', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: hamstring', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: leg', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: shin', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: shin', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Austin Collie', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Dan Connolly', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Questionable: finger', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: head', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Alfonzo Dennard', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Probable: ankle', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Questionable: leg', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: knee', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: knee', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: knee/shoulder', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: knee/shoulder', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: knee/shoulder', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Aaron Dobson', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Questionable: hamstring', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: hamstring', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Doubtful: shoulder', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: neck', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: neck', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: undisclosed', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: foot', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: foot', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: foot', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: foot', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Nate Ebner', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Questionable: ankle', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: ankle', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Questionable: ankle', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: ankle', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: ankle', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: ankle', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Julian Edelman', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: thigh', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: thigh', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Probable: thigh', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Dane Fletcher', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: groin', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: groin', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Tyronne Green', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed'}, {'Player': 'Steve Gregory', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Out: thumb', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Questionable: finger', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: finger', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: finger', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: finger', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: finger', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: knee/finger', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Cory Grissom', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: knee'}, {'Player': 'Rob Gronkowski', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Doubtful: arm/back', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: arm/back', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Doubtful: arm/back', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: arm/back', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Doubtful: arm/back', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: arm/back', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: arm/back', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Probable: back/forearm', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Probable: back/forearm/hamstring', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Probable: back/forearm/hamstring', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Probable: back/forearm/hamstring', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Probable: hamstring', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL'}, {'Player': 'Duron Harmon', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Questionable: hamstring', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: hamstring', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Mark Harrison', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Out: foot', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Out: foot', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Out: foot', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Out: foot', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Out: foot', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Out: foot', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Out: foot', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Out: foot', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Out: foot', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Out: foot', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Out: foot', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Out: foot', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Out: foot', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Out: foot', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Out: foot', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Out: foot', '01/11vs. IND': 'Out: foot', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Out: foot'}, {'Player': "Dont'a Hightower", '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: knee', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: knee', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Michael Hoomanawanui', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: knee', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: knee', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: knee', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Questionable: knee', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: knee', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Probable: knee', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: knee', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: knee', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Probable: knee', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Tommy Kelly', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: knee', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: knee', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: knee', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: knee', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: knee', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: knee'}, {'Player': 'Jerod Mayo', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: ankle', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: ankle', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: ankle', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: shoulder'}, {'Player': 'Devin McCourty', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: shoulder', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Probable: shoulder', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: head', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'T.J. Moe', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles'}, {'Player': 'Rob Ninkovich', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Probable: groin', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Probable: groin', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Probable: groin', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Questionable: foot', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: ankle', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Stevan Ridley', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Probable: shoulder', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: knee', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: knee', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Matt Slater', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: knee', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Out: wrist', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Out: wrist', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Out: wrist', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Out: wrist', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: wrist', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Probable: wrist', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Probable: wrist', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Probable: wrist', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Probable: wrist', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Probable: right shoulder', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Probable: wrist', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Nate Solder', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Probable: back', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: concussion', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: concussion', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: concussion', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Brandon Spikes', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Questionable: knee', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Probable: knee', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: knee', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: knee', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: knee', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: knee', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Zach Sudfeld', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: hamstring', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Probable: hamstring', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Probable: hamstring', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: hamstring', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Will Svitek', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Questionable: knee', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: knee', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Questionable: knee', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: knee', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: knee', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: ankle', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Aqib Talib', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: hip', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: hip', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: hip', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: hip', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Questionable: hip', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Questionable: hip', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: hip', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: hip', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: hip', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: hip', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Probable: hip', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Kenbrell Thompkins', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: shoulder', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Questionable: hip', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Questionable: hip', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: hip', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Questionable: hip', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Shane Vereen', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Out: wrist', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: wrist', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Probable: wrist', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Probable: wrist', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Probable: wrist', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Probable: wrist', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Questionable: groin', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Probable: groin', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Sebastian Vollmer', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: foot', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: foot', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: leg', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: leg'}, {'Player': 'Leon Washington', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: thigh', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Questionable: thigh', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Questionable: thigh', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: thigh', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: ankle', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: ankle', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: ankle', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: ankle', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Questionable: ankle', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Questionable: ankle', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Ryan Wendell', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: concussion', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Chris White', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'N/A', '10/13vs. NOR': 'N/A', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '10/27vs. MIA': 'N/A', '11/03vs. PIT': 'N/A', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Questionable: back', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Vince Wilfork', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Probable: foot', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Out: Achilles', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: Achilles'}, {'Player': 'Adrian Wilson', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: hamstring'}, {'Player': 'Tavon Wilson', '09/08vs. BUF': 'N/A', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'N/A', '09/22vs. TAM': 'N/A', '09/29vs. ATL': 'N/A', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Questionable: hamstring', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Questionable: hamstring', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Questionable: hamstring', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Questionable: hamstring', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Questionable: hamstring', '11/18vs. CAR': 'N/A', '11/24vs. DEN': 'N/A', '12/01vs. HOU': 'N/A', '12/08vs. CLE': 'N/A', '12/15vs. MIA': 'N/A', '12/22vs. BAL': 'N/A', '12/29vs. BUF': 'N/A', '01/11vs. IND': 'N/A', '01/19vs. DEN': 'N/A'}, {'Player': 'Markus Zusevics', '09/08vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '09/12vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '09/22vs. TAM': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '09/29vs. ATL': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/06vs. CIN': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/13vs. NOR': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/20vs. NYJ': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '10/27vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '11/03vs. PIT': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '11/18vs. CAR': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '11/24vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/01vs. HOU': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/08vs. CLE': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/15vs. MIA': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/22vs. BAL': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '12/29vs. BUF': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '01/11vs. IND': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', '01/19vs. DEN': 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed'}]
```